# Java & setting classpath & localization of packages

Tags: java, classpath, package

I've got structure of catalogs:

```
/home/etc./studies/JAVA/pack/Print.java
/home/etc./studies/JAVA/Lab2/zad1/pkg/A.java
/home/etc./studies/JAVA/Lab2/zad1/B.java
```

- A is a class in package "pkg"
- Print is a class in package "pack"
- B imports the packages "pkg" and "pack".

When I tried to compile B.java, I get an error:

```
B.java:4: error: cannot access A
public class B extends A{
                       ^
bad class file: /home/etc./studies/java/A.class
class file contains wrong class: pkg.A
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of 
the classpath.
```

Is it possible to include that packages without reorganization structure of files ?

Comment: In Java, the structure of the files is required to match the package structure.  You can work around this but it becomes unreasonably complicated.  Which IDE or build tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearly saying that:

class file contains wrong class name: `pkg.A`

that means probably you declared class name as pkg. An instead of A.
if you declare the package names as correct like this

```
home/etc/studies/JAVA/Lab2/zad1

home/etc/studies/JAVA/Lab2/zad1/pkg,

/home/etc/studies/JAVA/Lab2/zad1/B.java
```

You won't get the compilation error.

```
package home.etc.studies.JAVA.Lab2.zad1;

import home.etc.studies.JAVA.Lab2.zad1.pkg.A;

public class B extends A {
     'enter code here`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannotreference Classes in a default package. Put every class into a package.

Comment: Simple solution: If Print.java is shared by lots of classes, put it in a /utils package and include it in all that need it.